# Julia's equivalent of R's qnorm()?

Tags: r, julia, distribution, normal-distribution, quantile

I am trying to "translate" these lines from R to Julia:

```
n <- 100
mean <- 0
sd <- 1
x <- qnorm(seq(1 / n, 1 - 1 / n, length.out = n), mean, sd)
```

However, I have trouble with the qnorm function. I've searched for "quantile function" and found the `quantile()` function. However, the R's version returns a vector of length 100, while the Julia's version returns a vector of length 5.

Here's my attempt:

```
import Distributions
n = 100
x = Distributions.quantile(collect(range(1/n, stop=1-1/n, length=n)))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Under Julia 1.1 you should broadcast the call to `quantile` like this:

```
quantile.(Normal(0, 1), range(1/n, 1-1/n, length = n))
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
using Distributions
n = 100
qs = range(1/n, stop=1-1/n, length=n) # no need to collect it
d = Normal() # default is mean = 0, std = 1
result = [quantile(d, q) for q in qs]
```

Julia uses multiple dispatch to select the appropriate `quantile` method for a given distribution, in constrast to R where you seem to have prefixes. According to the [documentation](https://juliastats.github.io/Distributions.jl/stable/univariate.html#Base.quantile-Tuple%7BDistributions.Distribution%7BDistributions.Univariate,S%7D%20where%20S%3C:Distributions.ValueSupport,Real%7D) the first argument should be the distribution, the second argument the point where you want to evaluate the inverse cdf.

Strangely I get an error when I try to do `quantile.(d, qs)` (broadcast the quantile call). UPDATE: See Bogumil's answer in this case. In my benchmarks, both approaches have the same speed.

Comment: In my answer I show how to handle your issue with `broadcast`.